# dbGetQuery retrieves less number of rows

Tags: sql, r, hive, odbc

I am trying to fetch a large dataset into R environment using ODBC Connection

When I try to retrieve data from a large dataset using dbGetQuery() function, the number of rows are less than what is see on hive. Sometimes, the same code fetches me correct number of rows. Could some help me if i should clear any buffer before fetching the data?

```
hive_con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),.connection_string=Connection_String)
qry<-"select * from mytable"
rslt<-dbGetQuery(hive_con,qry)
```

I have tried changing n parameter of the function dbGetQuery(). But still the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i found that i was using HTTP protocol for data extraction. This protocol doesn't show any warning if the data loss happens.